# Missing operand with + on strings

Tags: c++

Based on seeing an apparent error in code that was compiling, I reduced it to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* p = "The ";
    string s = string("Bob ") + + "world.";
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

I would have thought maximal munch would see "+ +" as "++" and produce an error.

Comment: I'm surprised that compiled! See it here: http://ideone.com/2LEls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximal munch refers to processing a sequence of punctuation **without any spaces**.

Your code has spaces.  The parser/lexer won't create a single token when there's whitespace in the middle, because the grammar doesn't allow operators to contain whitespace.

Comment: @John there's no missing operand, the latter `+` is applied to `"world"`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, what does a unary `+` do to a string literal?

Comment: @MarkRansom the literal is promoted to a pointer to char, so it's a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

You're missunderstanding what "maximal munch" does - it doesn't magically concatenate operators - `+ +` doesn't become `++`. The latter one is applied to `"world."`, but that's it:

```
string s = string("Bob ") + (+"world.");
```

Think of

```
int x = +1;
```

Comment: @John nothing really, it's a no-op. `"world"` is a pointer, so applying `+` to it returns the same thing. Same as `+1` and `1` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No, `+ +` is not the same as `+`. The final subexpression is `+"world."`, which is a unary `+` on a pointer, which does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the space between the two `+`, each `+` is treated as a different token by the lexical analyzer.